# Twitter embed in a Chrome Extension with Manifest V3

Tags: google-chrome-extension, twitter, content-security-policy, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'd like to know if it's still possible to embed a Twitter Timelines in a Chrome Extension with a Manifest v3.

I tried to use from the Twitter docs :

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/TwitterDev?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">Tweets by TwitterDev</a> <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

But I get errors :

```
Refused to load the script 'https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.
```

```
Refused to load the script 'https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'wasm-unsafe-eval'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.
```

The problem if I understood correctly is that with manifest v3 it's not possible to use external scripts.

What are the possible solutions to embed a Twitter Timeline in a Chrome Extension ?

Thanks !

Comment: Do it inside `<iframe src="sandbox.html">` and declare this html as a [sandbox](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/manifest/sandbox/). Requires Chrome 110+.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thank you but at the moment I only have a Chrome 108 version

Comment: Well then install a newer portable version or Chrome Canary.

Comment: @wOxxOm Where are you getting "Requires Chrome 110+"? All the info I can find suggests it's been supported for years.

Comment: It worked for years in MV2. The retarded MV3 broke almost everything initially.